# Creating an 'environment' for Cloud Dataflow

Tags: python, dataframe, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

When I start my cloud dataflow job, I start by importing the libraries I need (in python). For example:

```
google-cloud-bigquery==1.3.0
pysftp==0.2.9
google-cloud-storage==1.10.0
pandas==0.23.3
pandas-gbq==0.5.0
jaydebeapi==1.1.1
apache-beam==2.5.0
elasticsearch==6.0.0
```

This usually takes several minutes to do each time and I use this same environment for every time I use Cloud Dataflow. Is there a way to "save" this environment, so that when the machine starts it is already 'ready'? I've seen "Templates", but it's only mentioned creating variables and such, not actually having libraries installed in an environment (or at least I haven't seen that).

If someone could show me an example of saving a library to an environment, that would be great, such as:

```
elasticsearch==6.0.0
```

Comment: Have you tried virtual environment?

Comment: @keineahnung2345 no -- I wasn't aware that was possible. How would that work with cloud dataflow -- i.e., how/where would I set it up?

Comment: Your local terminal . Step 4? https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-python#set-up-your-environment

Comment: @cricket_007 -- this doesn't run locally -- it starts off by starting a server and running the dataflow jobs. So my question would be how can I get those libraries pre-configured on the server(s) that start to run those jobs?

Comment: @cricket_007 also it states "It is recommended that you install a Python virtual environment **for initial experiments.**" My question is how do you get that installed for prod runs?

Comment: I think [this](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/) could solves your issue but it will install the dependencies in the remote workers. I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for... Can you explain more about "saving a library to an environment"? Do you mean to have this library permanent in your server?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your use case, you run the Dataflow job through some server.

In this case, you can specify libraries `--requirements_file` flag for PyPI Dependencies or `setup.py` for non-PyPI Dependencies. You have [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/) some examples and more details.